# Is an iOS development license with Unity free?

Tags: unity, c#, ios, xcode

I'm coding in Unity Personal and I'm going to try to put my game onto the App Store (through the Unity --> XCode --> App Store process). In the past, Unity has charged money to get a iOS license for this. The price was $400 I believe. I've certain articles that say that it has changed, and some that say it still costs money. So, I'm not sure which one is true. **Is creating and publishing a commercial game with Unity Personal now free? (meaning that there is no license required). If there is a price, how much is it, and is it a one-time fee or per month/year/game published etc.** Thanks! Also, can I legally make money with this game using the Unity Personal?

Comment: When in doubt, always check on Unity's website. It should have the most up to date details

Comment: I'll sift through the website today. I've already looked at lots of stuff there, but I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Unity personal tu publish a game on every platform for free but if you start making a revenue up to $100k per year you need to pay an annual plan, which starts at $40 per month. 
Here you have all the info for that in their site [Info of Unity Plans](https://store.unity.com/compare-plans)
On the other hand you should pay a developer license of each platform to publish. Every platform has their own fee, in the case of Apple is $99 per year. Here you can see more info about it [Apple dev program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/)